# Function of resistor in OpAmp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistors, input-impedance, guitar-pedal

I came across this circuit as part of a larger circuit in a guitar effect pedal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXyIJZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was wondering about the function of the resistor \$R_1\$. My calculations show that the same transfer function can be achieved with or without \$R_1\$ (leaving out \$R_1\$ just means that we need to change the other resistor values). The only difference that I can see is the change in input impedance of the circuit. Is this the only function of \$R_1\$ (i.e., reduce/define the input impedance), or is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Does your opamp have input bias current?

Comment: @sstobbe: It's a real circuit with a real opamp, so yes, it does. I do not know exactly which type of opamp is used in the original circuit.

Comment: R1 just biases input when not connected to a low R source to prevent noise. and gives low DC current.  for AC coupled inputs. R1 is larger than all the others

Comment: If the input on the left is ac coupled you will have to provide a path for the DC bias current I'm not sure the approach taken is the best

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75: The input of the circuit is connected to the output of another opamp (via an RC-low pass filter). Would your comment then still apply?

Comment: @sstobbe: The input is at half the power supply voltage (via R5, see modified diagram); I guess in that case there would be a path for the DC bias current, right?

Comment: Yes with R5, your covered for ib, under normal operation there will be ~0V across R1, hence its bootstrap and won't set the input resistance

Comment: R1 sets input impedance with  R2, R4+C1

Comment: Yes tony is correct, I thought R1 was across the input terminals in the org schematic

Comment: see my answer for a complete analysis with R5 and V+/2 source must be AC coupled to desired Cs*R5=T , so check Cs. you could also delete C1 and connect R4 to V+/2 as well, then HPF is controlled by Cs*R5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Reducing R1 from 100K to 1K lowers gain from 39dB to 38dB but reduces rolloff breakpoint to 8kHz. R1 also lowers input impedance so source impedance affects rolloff and gain is affected by source impedance if >= R1.

ADDITION of R5 makes R1 redundant and forces Vin to be AC coupled which affects HPF point and causes pop on plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the conclusion is that R1 is actually redundant? That was also my first thought, but my circuit knowledge is a bit rusty. Note that this is part of a circuit in a commercial device which has been sold many times, so I wonder if/how there can be such a design flaw (if it actually is one).

Comment: R5 makes R1 redundant since the DC voltage across +- inputs is always the same. whether biased to 0V for split supplies or V+/2 for single supply.  Use the largest V+ avail. to prevent saturation, unless you like fuzz guitar and note GBW needed for gain used. I chose 3MHz min for gain of 100 to give 30kHz BW